# telerik controls empty string passed to getelementbyid()

Tags: jquery, .net, vb.net, telerik

I inherited a web app that makes extensive use of telerik controls.

A couple of the page are pretty heavy on AJAX calls, typically setting some defaults when you choose a combo item (ex. pick a company, shipping addr fills in).

A day ago, this developed a strange behaviour. The very first ajax call would work, subsequent calls would not. Doesnt matter which one you do. First one works.

Looking at the browser console, you see the following during Page Load

```
TypeError: n is undefined
```

Furthermore, by invoking any ajax call, you will see messages like this

```
TypeError: n is undefined   (source script resource ... axd file)
TypeError: Empty string passed to getElementById()   (source jquery.js)
TypeError: b is null   (source script resource ... axd file)
```

I tried setting break points and looking back up the call chain to see which controls are spawning this.  Not very productive.

As I mentioned above, only the first call is working. Subsequent calls break. Any help as to why?

Comment: Is this a question?, or an info to the users?

Comment: sorry, in jeopardy fashion, ill pose this as a clear question and answer it below.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this saves someone some time.

There were some controls that we no longer wanted on the page. I commented them out  so we could 'get them back' next week when w changed our mind.

I happened to use a simple HTML comment  as opposed to the .NET/VB comment <%--  --%>

I believe what was happening is this. The code behind still knows about the control. I can verify this because it was referenced in code and not complaining.

Server side, Telerik renders JS code to assign event handler's to all the controls. Client side , since the Control is not actually there as expected the JS calls are not working as expected.  Thats fair, there is no practical way for Telerik to predict what the page will ultimately look like. Client side, they could check for existence before making the call.

Using a VB comment , and then commenting out the referencing code, or deleting the controls, :-) and then deleting the referencing code both resolve the problem.